# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" (type string) at path "_id" for model

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am developing an app but when i try to publish a course the error i am getting is kind of wired but might be related to the mongoose mondo db database.

```
export const publishCourse = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { courseId } = req.params;
    // find post
    const course = await Course.findById(courseId)
      .select("instructor")
      .exec();
    // is owner?
    if (course.instructor._id != req.user._id) {
      return res.status(400).send("Unauthorized");
    }

    const updated = await Course.findByIdAndUpdate(courseId, {published: true}, {new: true}).exec();

    res.json(updated);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(400).send("Publish course failed");
  }
};
```

Comment: I read this as "tried to convert undefined into a number". Which suggests `courseId` is undefined. Console.log it and find out. You can also look at the stack trace to see which line this is.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the parameter you retrieve from the request params `const { courseId } = req.params` is not a valid objectId hence `findById` throws the error you mentioned, try to make sure the `courseId` is a valid `objectId` before calling `findById`, maybe you can use this in your code:

```
const { courseId } = req.params;
if(ObjectId.isValid(courseId)){
  // throw some error document not found for example.
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).